# How to integrate registry edit script with exe execution with VBScript

Tags: windows, powershell, remote-server

I am trying to write script which should change the registry settings (WSUS server name) of remote servers. Once success script should execute exe and VBScript file stored on remote servers which installs patches on the server. below is my progress.

1. Change WSUS settings of the server. This is done, I am able to change WSUS server in registry on remote servers and get the result in a CSV file.
2. Once above step is successfull my below script should be able to execute mentioned command on remote servers, which is not happening currently.

Script:

```
#defined variables to use in script as below.##
$Computers = Get-Content "C:\serverlist.txt"
$Path      = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
$property  = "WUServer"
$value     = "http://serverFQDN"

$results = foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        try {
            Set-ItemProperty -Path $path -Name $Property -Value $Value -ErrorAction 'Stop'
            $status = "WSUS server has been set to http://serverFQDN"                          
            foreach ($computer in $Computers) {
                # below step is not getting executed on remote servers. I do not
                # get any error but above script do not execute any command on
                # remote servers.
                foreach ($computer in $computers) {
                    Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
                        C:\test\Patcher > cscript.exe -nologo test_v1.03.vbs /anlyze:false /reboot:false | Out-Null
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch {
            $status = "Failed"
        }
    } else {   
        $status = "Server is not reachable, please check connection and try again"
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
        'Computer' = $computer
        'Status'   = $status
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path "./out.csv"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't valid syntax:

```
C:\test\Patcher > cscript.exe -nologo test_v1.03.vbs ...
```

The statement would (try to) run a command `Patcher` located in the directory `C:\test` and redirect its output to a file `cscript.exe` in the current working directory.

You probably want to change the working directory to `C:\test\Patcher` and run `test_v1.03.vbs` from that directory. To do that change the above line to this:

```
Set-Location 'C:\test\Patcher'
& cscript.exe //NoLogo test_v1.03.vbs /anlyze:false /reboot:false | Out-Null
```

Comment: this has helped, but command gets execute only on the local server which I  am using to execute this script, it does not go to other servers mentioned in serverlist.txt

Comment: @VinitS To invoke a command on a remote computer you need to actually invoke the command on a remote computer: `Invoke-Command -Computer $computer -ScriptBlock {...}`